Chrome Extension OAuth 2.0 not working with Edge browser- Chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow giving "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"
I am developing a Chrome extension that uses chrome.identity.getAuthtoken API - to handle Google OAuth 2.0 authentication.

In Chrome browser it's working fine.

However, this API is not supported in the Microsoft Edge browser (link here). So as per suggestions in multiple forums, I am trying to use  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow API to handle Google OAuth 2.0 authentication for Microsoft Edge.
But the chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow API is not working  & is returning

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch



I couldn't find any documentation or discussion explaining this behavior on Edge or other Chromium-based browsers.
m questions-
Q1. Is there a specific configuration required in the Google Cloud Console to support other Chromium-based browsers (like Edge) when using Chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow?
Q2. Does Edge handle chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow differently, causing it to reject the redirect_uri?
Are there any known limitations or workarounds for this issue in Chromium-based browsers other than Chrome?
Footnote: I received a response mentioning that while the redirect_uri typically takes the format https://.chromiumapp.org/, in Edge, you still need to explicitly add the Edge-specific redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console OAuth 2.0 Client ID configuration, even if the extension ID remains the same. I have followed this suggestion, but the issue persists.
Thank you for your help!

I also bumped into that error 400, but the problem did get fixed. I created a new client ID and added https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/ among the list of Authorized redirect URIs. When I changed my redirect_uri to this URL, it worked fine again. Maybe you can try creating a new client ID? Also, if you have this problem with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow in Microsoft Edge, then Chrome should share the same behavior. Have you checked it?

Google OAuth requires that redirect_uri used in the authentication request must
exactly match one of the authorized redirect URIs specified in your Google Cloud Console project.
When using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, the redirect_uri is typically:
https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/

In Edge, the extension-id may remain the same, but you still need to explicitly add the Edge-specific redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console OAuth 2.0 Client ID configuration.
Hopefully this will work out:

Go to the Credentials section in your Google Cloud Console.
Find the OAuth 2.0 Client ID used by your extension.
Edit the client ID settings to include:

https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/

What web developers should know about Error 400.

Hi ,@schmark I am already using that. But issue still persist.
